# Foreach with promises javascript

Tags: javascript, ember.js

The function:

```
users.forEach(function(user) {
    window.server.users.add(user);
});
```

What i want is wait until the value was "successfully" insert and only then add the next one. And this repeat until end of the foreach. The "add" function is returning a promise by default, but i dont know how i have to change the code to do this.

```
users.forEach(function(user) {
    window.server.users.add(user).then(function(){
    //insert finished
    });
});
```

Comment: jquery has an `each` and a `promise` that you can possibly use together

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `forEach`. Keep your own index variable, and define a function which uses it and then enqueues itself in the callback of the promise.

```
var i = 0;
addUser = function () {
  if (i >= users.length) return;

  window.server.users.add(users[i++]).then(addUser);
}

addUser();
```

Comment: That doesn't look valid: `return if i > users.length;`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the promise implementation follows the standard Promise/A+ proposal, you can chain the promises, by returning a new promise form the `then` callback:

```
var promise = window.server.users.add(users[0]);
users.slice(1).forEach(function(user) {
    promise = promise.then(function() {
        return window.server.users.add(user);
    });
});
```